# Does storing ASCII files as a BLOB field in MySQL or Oracle offer a reduction in storage requirements?

Tags: mysql, storage, blob

I have several thousand small ASCII files containing 3D cartesian coordinates for atoms in molecules (among other information) that I need to store somewhere.

A simple calculation told me that we will require several terrabytes of space, which may be reduced to several gigabytes at most, but is not manageable under current infrastructural constraints. Somebody told me some people have stored similar numbers of files (of the same format, but sometimes bzipped) in MySQL and Oracle as a BLOB field. My question is, does storing such files as BLOB offer some form of reduction in storage requirements? If yes, how much of a reduction can I expect?

This is example text from an ASCII file that needs to be stored:

```
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
****
    5     4     1     1     0
SMALL
GAST_HUCK


@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C1         -9.7504    2.6683    0.0002 C.3       1 <1>        -0.0776 
      2 H1         -8.6504    2.6685    0.0010 H         1 <1>         0.0194 
      3 H2        -10.1163    2.1494   -0.8981 H         1 <1>         0.0194 
      4 H3        -10.1173    3.7053   -0.0004 H         1 <1>         0.0194 
      5 H4        -10.1176    2.1500    0.8982 H         1 <1>         0.0194 
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1    1    2 1    
     2    1    3 1    
     3    1    4 1    
     4    1    5 1    
@<TRIPOS>SUBSTRUCTURE
     1 ****        1 TEMP              0 ****  ****    0 ROOT 
@<TRIPOS>NORMAL
@<TRIPOS>FF_PBC
FORCE_FIELD_SETUP_FEATURE Force Field Setup information
v1.0  0 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 NONE 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: please read "we will require several terrabytes of space, which may be reduced to several gigabytes at most," as "we will require several terrabytes of space, which may be reduced to several gigabytes at most by zipping it up, "

Comment: So it is *really* only "several thousand small ASCII files" or are we talking millions, or billions? You would need over a billion files shown as above (~900 bytes) to reach a terabyte (a trillion+ bytes) in space, *uncompressed*.

Comment: Perhaps a helpful article: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/11/mysql-blob-compression-performance-benefits/

Answer (score 1):

Storing data in a `BLOB` column offers no form of reduction in storage requirements.  The storage requirements for `BLOB` types are simple:

- `TINYBLOB`       L + 1 bytes, where L < 2<sup>8</sup>
- `BLOB`              L + 2 bytes, where L < 2<sup>16</sup>
- `MEDIUMBLOB` L + 3 bytes, where L < 2<sup>24</sup>
- `LONGBLOB`      L + 4 bytes, where L < 2<sup>32</sup>

`L` represensts the length of the string data in bytes.

See [Storage Requrements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html) for further details.

If there is no need to search the contents of the molecule files in your database, you can reduce the storage requirements by compressing the data prior to inserting it or using the MySQL [COMPRESS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress) function on insert.

I think that addressed your main question, and based on those figures and how many files you plan to store based on an average size, you can calculate how much storage space will be consumed by the `BLOB` type columns.